# AudioPlayerError: write EPIPE ytdl-core discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord.js, audio-player

I have been trying to make a **music** system to play songs in vcs using **ytdl-core** and **ytsearcher** while using **discord js v13** for the bot. But I encounter a long **error** here it is:

```js
node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

AudioPlayerError: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writevGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:143:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:793:11)
    at Socket._writev (node:net:802:8)
    at doWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:406:12)
    at clearBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:561:5)
    at onwrite (node:internal/streams/writable:461:7)
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:106:10)
Emitted 'error' event on AudioPlayer instance at:
    at OggDemuxer.onStreamError (E:\_Documents\iobotnew\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:956:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at OggDemuxer.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  resource: <ref *3> AudioResource {
    playStream: OggDemuxer {
      _readableState: ReadableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
        length: 0,
        pipes: [],
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        constructed: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: true,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        errorEmitted: true,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        destroyed: true,
        errored: Error: write EPIPE
            at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
            at writevGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:143:3)
            at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:793:11)
            at Socket._writev (node:net:802:8)
            at doWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:406:12)
            at clearBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:561:5)
            at onwrite (node:internal/streams/writable:461:7)
            at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:106:10) {
          errno: -4047,
          code: 'EPIPE',
          syscall: 'write'
        },
        closed: true,
        closeEmitted: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrainWriters: null,
        multiAwaitDrain: false,
        readingMore: false,
        dataEmitted: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
      },
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
        close: [
          [Function (anonymous)],
          [Function: onclose],
          [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: onFailureCallback]
          }
        ],
        end: [
          [Function: onend],
          [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: onFailureCallback]
          }
        ],
        finish: [
          [Function: onfinish],
          [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: onFailureCallback]
          }
        ],
        error: [Function: onerror],
        readable: [
          [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function (anonymous)]
          },
          [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: onReadableCallback]
          }
        ]
      },
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        afterWriteTickInfo: null,
        buffered: [],
        bufferedIndex: 0,
        allBuffers: true,
        allNoop: true,
        pendingcb: 0,
        constructed: true,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: true,
        emitClose: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        errored: Error: write EPIPE
            at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
            at writevGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:143:3)
            at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:793:11)
            at Socket._writev (node:net:802:8)
            at doWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:406:12)
            at clearBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:561:5)
            at onwrite (node:internal/streams/writable:461:7)
            at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:106:10) {
          errno: -4047,
          code: 'EPIPE',
          syscall: 'write'
        },
        closed: true,
        closeEmitted: false,
        [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
      },
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _remainder: null,
      _head: null,
      _bitstream: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    edges: [
      <ref *1> {
        type: 'ffmpeg ogg',
        to: Node {
          edges: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
          type: 'ogg/opus'
        },
        cost: 2,
        transformer: [Function: transformer],
        from: Node { edges: [ [Object], [Circular *1] ], type: 'arbitrary' }
      },
      <ref *2> {
        type: 'ogg/opus demuxer',
        to: Node { edges: [ [Object] ], type: 'opus' },
        cost: 1,
        transformer: [Function: transformer],
        from: Node {
          edges: [ [Circular *2], [Object], [Object] ],
          type: 'ogg/opus'
        }
      }
    ],
    metadata: null,
    volume: undefined,
    encoder: undefined,
    audioPlayer: <ref *4> AudioPlayer {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] { idle: [Function (anonymous)] },
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _state: {
        status: 'buffering',
        resource: [Circular *3],
        onReadableCallback: [Function: onReadableCallback],
        onFailureCallback: [Function: onFailureCallback],
        onStreamError: [Function: onStreamError]
      },
      subscribers: [
        PlayerSubscription {
          connection: VoiceConnection {
            _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
            _eventsCount: 0,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            rejoinAttempts: 0,
            _state: [Object],
            joinConfig: [Object],
            packets: [Object],
            receiver: [VoiceReceiver],
            debug: null,
            onNetworkingClose: [Function: bound onNetworkingClose],
            onNetworkingStateChange: [Function: bound onNetworkingStateChange],
            onNetworkingError: [Function: bound onNetworkingError],
            onNetworkingDebug: [Function: bound onNetworkingDebug],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          player: [Circular *4]
      ],
      behaviors: { noSubscriber: 'pause', maxMissedFrames: 5 },
      debug: [Function (anonymous)],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    playbackDuration: 0,
    started: false,
    silencePaddingFrames: 5,
    silenceRemaining: -1
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me here is my **code**:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioResource, createAudioPlayer, AudioPlayerStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const { YTSearcher } = require('ytsearcher');

const searcher = new YTSearcher({
    key: "myyoutubeapikey",
    revealKey: true
})

module.exports = {

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .setDescription('Permet de jouer de la musique dans votre salon vocal !')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('song').setDescription('Le nom de la musique / URL').setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {

        const song = interaction.options.getString('song');
        let vc = interaction.member.voice.channel;
        if(!vc){
            return interaction.reply({ content: ":warning: **- Vous devez être dans un salon vocal pour pouvoir jouer de la musique !**", ephemeral: true });
        }
        let result = await searcher.search(song, { type: "video" })
        console.log(result.first.url)

        const stream = ytdl(result.first.url, {
            filter: "audioonly",
        });

        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

        const connections = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: vc.id,
            guildId: vc.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: vc.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        })

        player.play(resource);
        connections.subscribe(player);

        player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
            connections.destroy();
        });
    }

};
```

I tried a lot of things and I looked before making this post if someone already had the same problem (with the same context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
const stream = ytdl(result.first.url, {
            filter: "audioonly",
        });
```

on the

```
const stream = ytdl(result.first.url, {
            filter: "audioonly",
            quality: 'highestaudio',
            highWaterMark: 1 << 25
        });
```